# how to sanitise input from an HTTP parameter flows into send

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my first time trying to protect from XSS. When I use code analysis from Snyk, it gives the below warning about cross-script attack. The line with error is used to delete order so I am not sure what alternative code to replace or how to sanitize the input. Please advice on how to sanitize the input.

> Unsanitized input from an HTTP parameter flows into send, where it is used to render an HTML page returned to the user. This may result in a Cross-Site Scripting attack (XSS).

the line which is in risk of XSS

```
res.send(deletedOrder)
```

Comment: Try [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Sanitizer/sanitize)

Comment: I had a similar issue with Snyk reviewing some PHP code. The GET parameter was validated to be an integer within a specific range, and only then included in a string containing an HTML meta-refresh (When provided, a dashboard page was to refresh at a specified seconds interval. When omitted, the meta-refresh was not included in the page). Even santitized, it showed the error. Not sure if I'm missing something or if Snyk isn't checking deep enough. I even tried wrapping it in htmlentities in the original use, but it didn't change the warning.

Comment: The Sanitizer API is (as of May 22, 2021) experimental, isn't it?  It must be manually enabled in browsers, so perhaps it is not the right general-purpose solution at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with a @PostMapping POST request that was getting a json POJO in input returning a string id.
The error states that the problem is returning an HTTP page but actually for me it was just a string, so by adding the content return type as `text/plain` I cleared the error:

```
  @PostMapping(path ="/mymapping", produces="text/plain")
```

Hope this helps!